# trying to seperate real and imaginary but it gets add up

Tags: python, numpy

I have given a set of array where it contains real and imaginary values . I need to separate them and print it out . but its not working out . the output gives

> [3. +0.j 4.5+0.j 0. +0.j]

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([3,4.5,3+5j,0])
real = np.isreal(array)
print(array[real])
img = np.iscomplex(array)
print(array[img])
```

Comment: @TomDalton just need to separate real and imaginary values

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.real.html) documentation you should do the following:

```
print(array.real)
print(array.imag)
```

Comment: its not giving the output required .
> [3.  4.5 3.  0. ]

Comment: for me it works, what is the output you get?
Are you able to reproduce the example in the link above?

Answer (score 0):

is this right?

```
import numpy as np


array = np.array([3,4.5,3+5j,0, 12.5])
real = np.isreal(array)

#here I check to prevent round number and just cast number like 12.0 1.0 to int
print([int(i) if str(i).rsplit(".", 1)[-1] == '0' else i for i in array[real].real  ])

img = np.iscomplex(array)

print([complex(int(i.real),i.imag) for i in array[img]])
```

output:

```
[3, 4.5, 0, 12.5]
[(3+5j)]
```

I just append 12.5 for test to see how it's working!

Comment: this is wat I want but I want it in integer instead of float .
like [3   4.5   0]
[3+5j]

Comment: @rahuldbz what do u think?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking is to print the real numbers if it does not have any imaginary number. If it has imaginary part, then just print the imaginary part.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([3,4.5,3+5j,0])
real = np.isreal(array)
print(array[real].real)
img = np.iscomplex(array)
print(array[img].imag)

# output

[ 3.   4.5  0. ]
[5.]
```